# How many Gods are in Christianity?

Tags: protestantism

How many Gods are in John 1-2 "1 In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. 2 He was with God in the beginning." ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What qualifies the 3 entities of the Trinity as one?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/what-qualifies-the-3-entities-of-the-trinity-as-one)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Biblical basis for the doctrine of the Trinity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-doctrine-of-the-trinity)

Answer (score 4):

There's only one God, his name is Yahweh, His son Jesus Christ and The Holy Spirit. One God in three persons. In one instance in John 14:9 Jesus says to one of the desciples, who asked of him to show them The Father: "If you see me, you've seen my Father" - meaning, they are one. Obviously, Jesus is The Son of God, but also one with The Father. A triune God if you will.

Comment: Hi Ivan.  This doesn't quite address the specific passage quoted by the OP, though you could make a connection between the two.

Comment: Fair enough, but I went with some universal truth, of how the majority of christians view the trinity - hence, Jesus was present with the Father but it was still one God.