# Don't understand the Trinity doctrine

Tags: life-of-jesus, trinity, logic, theophany, tertullian

Tried to understand the doctrine deeply and in a broader way than it is taught in school, or presented in Wikipedia.

And no one can explain it to me in a simple way for my mind to accept it, 
How it can be that:

```
x = G 
y = G
z = G 
BUT! 
x != y != z != x
```

And even in this [site](http://www.allaboutgod.com/trinity-doctrine.htm) the authors of the site have written without no doubt:

> The most difficult thing about the Trinity Doctrine is that there is no way to adequately explain it. The Trinity is a concept that is impossible for any human being to fully understand, let alone explain

In the end the authors just throw at me their problems:

> This is a difficult concept to grasp. But let's put a God-sized doctrine into perspective -- God is beyond our comprehension.

Logically, something does not work out for me, The Almighty **will not allow** us to believe that there is a triangle with four sides, or that he will create a square whose diameter is equal to its side. Of course it **"is a difficult concept to grasp"**, because maybe they have disrupted the intent of Christ, who can tell me that Christ accept Tertullian:

> new theological concepts and advanced the development of early Church doctrine.

I'm desperate to understand the truth, and to settle this problem.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but your formulation that `x = G`... is not consistent with Trinitarian theology. Are you looking for a full explanation of the Trinity? That is probably to broad for a single question.

Comment: Execuse me dear bradimus  but I think you should check agian what the Trinitarian theology is saying, have a look at the "Scutum Fidei" or as we all say "Shield of the Trinity". Shorcut for you:

"The Father is God"
"The Son is God"
"The Holy Spirit is God"
"God is the Father"
"God is the Son"
"God is the Holy Spirit"
"The Father is not the Son"
"The Father is not the Holy Spirit"
"The Son is not the Father"
"The Son is not the Holy Spirit"
"The Holy Spirit is not the Father"
"The Holy Spirit is not the Son"

Comment: "is" and "equals" are not the same. See https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53289/what-is-the-meaning-of-is-in-the-context-of-the-trinity

Comment: This site doesn't accept "truth" questions (see [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3527/32540)). Different Christian groups will have different perspectives on your question. For example, see these 2 opposing questions: [What is the Biblical basis for the doctrine of the Trinity?](//christianity.stackexchange.com/q/72) and [What is the Biblical basis for disbelief in the doctrine of the Trinity?](//christianity.stackexchange.com/q/18043)

Comment: @4castle Very interesting aspect about the site, I felt it from the moment I started to read the answers for the questions. But what you offer as an answer ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It is possible that the concept of the Trinity is not a simple one.